# Kendo grid from html table crashes

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have the following html in **About.cshtml**

```
<div>
 @Html.Partial("_SearchPanel", Model.scM)
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)

   </div>
</div>
```

**_MapDetailsList.cshtml**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails">

  <thead>
   ....
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   .....
   </tbody>
```

Lots of data binding from model goes into the table and works perfectly until i try to convert it into a **kendoGrid**

**Before adding .kendoGrid script**[image]

**Script in About.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#MapDetails").kendoGrid(
        {
            //sortable: true,
            dataSource: {
                pageSize: 5
            },
            pageable:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

then I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

If I replace `#MapDetails` in the script with `#mapsDiv`, nodeName error disappears

and Page nos start appearing as bullet points and datarows appear before the headers
[image]

if I say

```
$(".row").kendoGrid(...
```

there's madness: even the searchpanel gets paginated

[image]

Any clues please?

I have the following scripts/style sheets on page

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
"~/Content/bootstrap.css"
"~/Content/Site.css"                     
"~/Content/freelancer.min.css"
"~/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"
"~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css"
"~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css"
"~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"
"~/Scripts/modernizr-*"
"~/Scripts/freelancer.js",
"~/Scripts/freelancer.min.js"
"~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js",
"~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
"~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I totally had to scrap away this approach and create grid from js. As i didnot have linear data, so had to do lots of work arounds too